# Trying to get a dropdown working in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to get a dropdown working in asp.net core but it doesnt even appear to like the first list that its supposed to populate staff memebers with. I have a table called activity header with a foreignkey field staff id linked to a staff table.

First here is the code I am trying from this tutorial

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetStaff()
{
        List <SelectListItem> staff = _db.Staff.AsNoTracking();

            List <SelectListItem> selectListItems = _db.Staff.AsNoTracking()
                .OrderBy(n => n.FirstName)
                    .Select(n =>
                    new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Value = n.StaffID.ToString(),
                        Text = n.FirstName.ToString() + " " + n.LastName.ToString()
                    }).ToList();
            var stafftip = new SelectListItem()
            {
                Value = null,
                Text = "--- select staff memeber---"
            };
            staff.Insert(0, stafftip );
            return new SelectList(staff, "Value", "Text");

}
```

My Class for activity header

```
 public class ActivityHeader
 { 
    // other fields removed for brevity

    [Required]        
    [Display(Name = "Staff")]
    public int StaffId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Staff> Staff { get; set; }
 }
```

My staff class here which should link to the other table with the staff id

```
public class Staff
{
    [Key]
    public int StaffID { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

    public string StaffNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Staff> Staff { get; set; }
 }
```

This is my html for my view which is inside a bootstrap popup.

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
     <label for="inputPostalCode">SOP</label>
   <div class="form-group">
     @Html.LabelFor(x => Model.Staff, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-5">
       @Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.StaffId, new SelectList(Model.Staff, "Value", "Text"), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", id = "Country" })
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.StaffId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

What i expect to see is a html drop down with the results from staff but linked to activity head with staff id.

But it doesn't appear to like this list for some reason. Exact error is

[image]

Comment: Could you provide the exact error?

Comment: @eVolve please see screen shot of error added

Comment: @Dave Please check my answer and let me know your feedback.

Comment: @TanvirArjel just in work will when i get home this is a home project just

Answer (score 1):

I see there are few mistakes in your `DropDownList` implementation:

**Number #1 :**

If you want if no item is selected from `DropDownList` then `null` value for the select list will be passed then don't need to set `DropDownList` level text as follows:

```
var stafftip = new SelectListItem()
{
            Value = null,
            Text = "--- select staff memeber---"
};
staff.Insert(0, stafftip );
```

Rather simply your `GetStaff()` method as follows:

```
public SelectList GetStaff()
{
     var staffList = _db.Staff.Select(s => new
     {
           Value = s.StaffID,
           Text = s.FirstName + " " + s.LastName
     }).ToList();

    return new SelectList(staffList, "Value", "Text");
}
```

Now in your model classes, replace `public virtual IEnumerable<Staff> Staff { get; set; }` with `public SelectList  Staff { get; set; }`

Then in the view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.StaffId, Model.Staff,"Select Staff", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", id = "Country" })
```

**Number #2:**

If you want, if no item is selected from `DropDownList` then `default (0 or anything)` value for the select list will be passed then write your `GetStaff()` method as follows:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetStaff()
{
    List<SelectListItem> staffSelectListItems = _db.Staff.OrderBy(n => n.FirstName)
                                   .Select(n => new SelectListItem
                                   {
                                       Value = n.StaffID.ToString(),
                                          Text = n.FirstName.ToString() + " " + n.LastName.ToString()
                                   }).ToList();

    var defaultSelection = new SelectListItem()
    {
                Value = "0",
                Text = "Select Staff Member",
                Selected = true // <-- this is obligatory
    };
    staffSelectListItems.Insert(0, defaultSelection);
    return staffSelectListItems;
}
```

Then in the view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.StaffId,(List<SelectListItem>)Model.Staff, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", id = "Country" })
```

Hope it will now work for you!

Answer (score 0):

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetStaff()
{
    List <SelectListItem> selectListItems = _db.Staff.AsNoTracking()
         .OrderBy(n => n.FirstName)
         .Select(n =>
            new SelectListItem
                 {
                     Value = n.StaffID.ToString(),
                     Text = n.FirstName.ToString() + " " + n.LastName.ToString()
                 }).ToList();
    var stafftip = new SelectListItem()
       {
          Value = null,
          Text = "--- select staff memeber---"
       };

   selectListItems.Insert(0, stafftip );
   return new SelectList(selectListItems, "Value", "Text");        
}
```

You were trying to assign an IQueryable to a List which wasn't going to work. I have removed that line and fixed your use of the selectlist as staff is not needed.